# Div inside php. Webshop thumbnails

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, webshop

I'm creating a webshop sort of thing without paying.
I want to create things like thumbnails, so you can see how a product is called and how it looks like.
this is what the thumbnail looks like atm.
[image]

I use this code to create this:

```
<div class="product">
        <?php
          include 'assets/php_includes/db_connection.php';

          $query = "SELECT * FROM artikelen";
          $result = mysqli_query($DB_CONNECTION, $query);

          if ($result === false) {
            die(mysql_error());
          }

          while($artikel = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($artikel['Ingeschakeld'] === 1) {
              echo "" . $artikel['Naam'] . "<br>";
              echo "" . $artikel['Prijs'] . "<br>";
              echo "" . $artikel['Informatie'] . "<br>";
              echo "" . $artikel['Ingeschakeld'] . "<br>";
            } else {
              echo "This article isn't available!";
            }
          }
        ?>
      </div>
```

But all the different items come in 1 thumbnail.
How would I make it so it would make multiple thumbnails with only 1 code like this?

Comment: Put `div` inside while loop.

Comment: just like that, or do I have to put it in echo and then between ''s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below. Just an example.

```
<style>
.product{

    border: 2px solid #808080;
    width: 205px;
    height: 205px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<?php
            $artikel = array(array('Naam'=>"Naam 1", "Prijs"=>"Prijs 1", "Informatie"=>"Informatie 1", "Ingeschakeld"=>1),
                               array('Naam'=>"Naam 2", "Prijs"=>"Prijs 2", "Informatie"=>"Informatie 2", "Ingeschakeld"=>1),
                               array('Naam'=>"Naam 3", "Prijs"=>"Prijs 3", "Informatie"=>"Informatie 3", "Ingeschakeld"=>2),
                               array('Naam'=>"Naam 4", "Prijs"=>"Prijs 4", "Informatie"=>"Informatie 4", "Ingeschakeld"=>1),
                               array('Naam'=>"Naam 5", "Prijs"=>"Prijs 5", "Informatie"=>"Informatie 5", "Ingeschakeld"=>1),
                              );

                foreach($artikel as $artikel)
                    {

                        ?>
                        <div class="product">
                            <?php
                         if ($artikel['Ingeschakeld'] === 1) {      
                                  echo "" . $artikel['Naam'] . "<br>";
                                  echo "" . $artikel['Prijs'] . "<br>";
                                  echo "" . $artikel['Informatie'] . "<br>";
                                  echo "" . $artikel['Ingeschakeld'] . "<br>";
                            } else {
                                echo "This article isn't available!";
                            }  
                            ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php
                    }

?>
```

Comment: I can do it like that, but then I would have to add the code between the div tags like 200 times? I was thinking of just using a loop to loop through all the rows I have in my database and add it. isn't there a way to do this?

Comment: `add the code between the div tags like 200 times?` Sorry, I didn't get it.

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx In your case, `$artikel` data come from DB & about Readability, I didn't use any Comment or proper Indentation since it's just an example. You can adapt the same by refering http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code--net-8118